# Is there a here-api to get ETA for a particular destination?

Tags: here-api

I want to calculate ETA for a specific  destination using here-api.

Right now we are using calculateroute API which provides "Travel duration" only(does not provide time of arrival).
Thus when we need ETA for example "Whats the ETA to santa cruz", are we expected to calculate "current time + travel duration" and reply with "Time of arrival"?

With the above method scenario there will be challenges like 
1. Date rollover. 
2. Timezone change.

So, Is there any API where HERE provides ETA when a destination is sent as parameter in api call.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any parameter to get direclty ETA in local time, but:

1/ You can get timezone via Reverse Geocoding REST API, when specifying locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone

[Exemple of RGC request](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=XXXX&app_code=YYYY&prox=LAT,LNG&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&locationattributes=adminInfo,timeZone)

2/ You can then calculate ETA by taking in account the travel duration and difference of timezone between departure and arrival.